# Xamarin iOS app crashes with +[MSAppDelegateForwarder addAppDelegateSelectorToSwizzle:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, visual-studio-app-center

I am trying to get an existing Xamarin native iOS app using MvvmCross to build and deploy but it crashes on every startup with

```
+ "[MSAppDelegateForwarder addAppDelegateSelectorToSwizzle:]: unrecognized selector sent to class"
```

Searching around on "MSAppDelegateForwarder addAppDelegateSelectorToSwizzle" I see a lot of references to the Microsoft App Center project. I have disabled App Center in the app and uninstalled the packages but am still getting this error.

I have also discovered that I am getting this error logged on build

```
Class MSService is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices (0x2718caf70) and /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3FDD6329-9949-4E57-8CA1-7E295EABC7F0/(MyApp).iOS.app/(MyApp).iOS (0x106c54118). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I have cleaned, rebuilt, deleted bin and obj files, deleted the packages file and even removed and reinstalled Visual Studio Mac. I am not sure where to go from here. Has anyone run into this exception before?

Comment: Can you try disabling swizzling in AppCenter? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin#disable-automatic-forwarding-of-application-delegates-methods-to-app-center-services and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-ios#disable-automatic-method-forwarding-to-app-center-services. What AppCenter modules are used?

Comment: your second question (about class being implemented in two files) is "solved" in this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581884/class-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used

Comment: Great suggestion on disabling swizzling, however that did not work.