# Class is implemented in both when running IOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using `cocoapods version 1.9.1` and `Xcode 11.3.1`

I'm following this tutorial https://docs.snapchat.com/docs/tutorials/login-kit/ios/

I keep getting this error that says `class` is implemented in both when running my app on IOS simulator, the problem lies in `CoreSimulator/Devices`

```
Class SCSDKCertificateTrust is implemented in both 
/Users/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EB370499-8654-42DD-9FC0- 
F7ACB17C0532/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/695ED9C1-3329-457C-BCED- 
3670C52E4E19/Test.app/Frameworks/SCSDKLoginKit.framework/SCSDKLoginKit (0x1033dba50) and 
/Users/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EB370499-8654-42DD-9FC0- 
F7ACB17C0532/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/695ED9C1-3329-457C-BCED- 
3670C52E4E19/Test.app/Frameworks/SCSDKCoreKit.framework/SCSDKCoreKit (0x10339b098). One of 
the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

My Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Test' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Test
  pod 'SnapSDK'

end
```

I'm not sure how to fix this problem and I have searched the net and found multiple solutions especially on SO

1. [Class is implemented in both. One of the two will be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581884/class-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used)
2. [Class is implemented in both, One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932341/class-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used-which-one-is-undefined)

Unfortunately most of the solutions are about fixing it on `.xcconfig` file and remove in `OTHER_LDFLAGS.`

I tried those two solutions and it didn't work, could it be because of the cocoapods version?

because I tried this on my Xcode 10 version and still produced the same problem

Comment: Found an answer yet?

Comment: @AakashDave airsoftFreak - Have you got any solution for this ?

Comment: @Mrunal Honestly no mate. I even reached the snap team, they too were unable to solve this for some reason. So I ended up creating a new project

Answer (score 0):

For me:
Go to your Project in the top of the file navigator in Xcode and click Package Dependencies. Remove any dependencies that you may have installed using 'Add Package' instead of with cocoapods, or that may be causing the error.