# XCFramework problem, EXC_BAD_ACCESS after loading

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcframework

I have built a private XCFramework, and it works just fine in the project where I have it attached, after building, it links well, the app launches and then when I use it it crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on a static let, or sometimes some other part of the Application. The Framework has POD dependencies and it is distributed through a POD, although I've tried changing the framework itself for a debug copy of it and it does the same. Has anyone encountered this issue? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I've ended finding the answer here, problem was the pods where not statically linked with the framework: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67641220/770998